# How to Re-direct my blog http://subdomain.example.com to https://

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, redirect, https

For redirecting my sub domain `http:` to `https:`

I used below code in `.htaccess` file but it didn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://subdomain.example.com/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Also, I have already changed from `http` to `https` in WordPress site URL, but still it is not working.

Please guide me how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Practice: 301 Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Standard Domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029049/best-practice-301-redirect-http-to-https-standard-domain)

Comment: Don't create duplicate questions. This has been asked a great many times already on this site.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^$ https://subdomain.example.com/ [R=301,NE,NC,L]
> ```

This simply checks the *host*, not the SSL state (ie. HTTP or HTTPS). This also only redirects the site root and would result in a redirect loop.

Try the following instead. This will need to go *before* the existing (WordPress) directives in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.