# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Standard Domain) - with New Google Chrome Rules

Tags: .htaccess

I have used the following redirect within .htaccess to force HTTPS for a long time with no problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However, it seems that Google Chrome's latest update gives me a security warning.

> Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
>   information from ofertaclarocloud.com.co (for example, passwords,
>   messages or credit cards). Learn more
>   NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID   Automatically send some system
>   information and page content to Google to help detect dangerous apps
>   and sites. Privacy Policy

Does anyone know any way around this?

(Note: I am using a form on the page. It does not, however, have any sensitive information such as passwords, credit card information, etc. Just a simple form with name, phone, and email.)

(Note 2: I have also tried a few other solutions around StackOverflow to such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029049/best-practice-301-redirect-http-to-https-standard-domain).)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe the issue is your `.htaccess` code. Have you made any changes to your code recently? I.e is there a HTTP url being served on the page?

Comment: Hi @Lag, thanks for your reply. The page in question is actually a new one, but I've done it for months on other pages with no problem at all. Then, regarding your second question, yes, the original url is http://...