# 301 Redirect HTTP to HTTPS - non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, http-redirect

I am searching for the perfect 301 redirect HTTP to HTTPS - non-www to www. But I can't find a working solution.

Here is what I want to do

```
http://domain.tld/ → https://www.domain.tld/
http://www.domain.tld/ → https://www.domain.tld/
https://domain.tld/ → https://www.domain.tld/
```

In this post: [Best Practice: 301 Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Standard Domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029049/best-practice-301-redirect-http-to-https-standard-domain)

It concludes:

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

but this is for www. to non-www.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need this for multiple domains, or just one, but here is an example where multiple domains are supported. Since you want www and https on all domains, I've just hardcoded it. This *should* also skip rewriting if there is a sub-domain in the url. You might need to adjust it to support TLDs with dots (i.e. .co.uk, .co.au etc).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```