# HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working with .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, https, redirect

I am trying to force my website to redirect http traffic to the https site and I have verified that the htaccess file is getting accessed but the redirect is not occurring. I have a valid cert for the site and the https version works fine but whether I type in www.mywebsite.com or http://www.mywebsite.com or website.com I still get taken to the HTTP version. Any suggestions?

**.htaccess file**

```
# Use PHP56
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

# Always Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this on my website and it redirects to HTTPS and not HTTP. There is also a great explanation here: [Best Practice: 301 Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (Standard Domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029049/best-practice-301-redirect-http-to-https-standard-domain)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I figured it out, I had my code snippet in the wrong htaccess file and this is why it wasn't triggering. I am still going to vote you correct though because your answer caused me to double check everything and figure out my mistake!

Comment: The same happened to me. I was adding the rule in the root folder `.htaccess` of my hosting, but I had to add it to the `www` folder, in which wordpress is installed (in my case). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by adding this code snippet, make sure it is at the beginning of the file .htaccess:

```
# Force HTTPS on all pages
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```